# Check, if a variable does not equal to any of the vector's elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a vector `dogSpecies` showing all four unique dog species under investigation.

```
#a set of possible dog species
dogSpecies = [1,2,3,4]
```

I also have a `data` vector containing integer numbers corresponding to the records of dog species of all dogs tested.

```
# species of examined dogs
data = np.array(1,1,2,-1,0,2,3,5,4)
```

Some of the records in `data` contain values different than 1,2,3 or 4. (Such as -1, 0 or 5). If an element in the `data` set is not equal to any element of the `dogSpecies`, such occurrence should be marked in an error evaluation boolean matrix as `False`.

```
#initially all the elements of the boolean error evaluation vector are True.

errorEval = np.ones((np.size(data,axis = 0)),dtype=bool)
```

Ideally my `errorEval` vector would look like this:

```
errorEval = np.array[True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, True]
```

I want a piece of code that checks if the elements of `data` are not equal to the elements of `dogSpecies` vector. My code for some reason marks every single element of the `errorEval` vector as 'False'.

```
for i in range(np.size(data, axis = 0)):
# validation of the species
            if (data[i] !=  dogSpecies):
                    errorEval[i] = False
```

I understand that I cannot compare a single element with a vector of four elements like above, but how do I do this then?

Comment: so you want a column indicating if the dog column value exists in your `dogSpecies` list, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Right now, you are checking if a data element (I'm assuming `int`) is not equal to a `list`, which will always evaluate as `False`

Comment: It is always helpful to provide a minimal example of the data/input and the expected result.  Please read [mcve]

Comment: As an aside, you can get a numpy array from a DataFrame column using its [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html?highlight=values#pandas.Series.values) attribute: `df.iloc[:,3].values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a dataframe and a list of dog species. This should achieve what you want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dog': [1,3,4,5,1,1,8,9,0]})

   dog
0    1
1    3
2    4
3    5
4    1
5    1
6    8
7    9
8    0


df['errorEval'] = df['dog'].isin(dogSpecies).astype(int)

   dog  errorEval
0    1          1
1    3          1
2    4          1
3    5          0
4    1          1
5    1          1
6    8          0
7    9          0
8    0          0

df.errorEval.values
# array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

If you don't want to create a new column then you can do:

```
df.assign(errorEval=df['dog'].isin(dogSpecies).astype(int)).errorEval.values
# array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: This is what I want to achieve, yes. I would just like to immediately have it in a separate vector and not in the data frame. Thanks anyway!

Comment: you don't need to set it in the dataframe, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just what you want?

```
for index, elem in enumerate(data):
    if elem not in dogSpecies:
        errorEval[index] = False
```

Probably not very fast, it doesn't use any vectorized numpy ufuncs but if the array isn't very large that won't matter. Converting `dogSpecies` to a `set` will also speed things up.

---

As an aside, your python looks very c/java esque. I'd suggest reading the [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: if OP clarifies,  a better more efficient approach, would be to use `pandas` functions only and convert to an array as the final step, that way it's vectorized

Answer (score 0):

As @FHTMitchel stated you have to use `in` to check if an element is in a list or not.
But you can use list comprehension which is faster as normal loop and shorter:

```
errorEval = np.array([True if elem in dogSpecies else False for elem in data])
```